SvelteKitError: Not found - requests flooding the web server
I have deployed SvelteKit application using pm2 and nginx on my Ubuntu LTS VPS server which works perfectly on my local, also on my VPS. But at random times, I got bad gateway errors and can't reach my VPS server using SSH.
I have examined my .pm2/logs/npm-error log file, and then I see tons of 404 requests that are unrelated with my routes/endpoints.
SvelteKitError: Not found: /lander/testsberv4_1703110539/
--- some locations on my code, that i handle auth (hooks.server.js)
  status: 404,
  text: 'Not Found'
...

SvelteKitError: Not found: //web/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
  status: 404,
  text: 'Not Found'

and so on. they aren't available routes on my application.
I am serving a necessary app, so it always should be up, at any time. But I can't figure out any solutions.

If it helps, I am using Lucia for auth and Prisma for db.

I have tried setting up Cloudflare with its default options
I have searched about pm2, but can't figure out anything
I am showing 404 for unrelated routes.

These requests are normal web server vulnerability scanning attacks. Any web server connected to Internet will get a fair share of these. Seeing thousands of requests a day or a hour is normal.
These kind of traffic is usually not a problem, because serving HTTP 404 is a very fast operation and does not tax the server. Maybe there is something special in your SvelteKit code or your VPS which causes unnecessary CPU load when serving 404 responses.

I can see CPU spikes in my CPU usage graph, it goes like 103%!! How can I prevent those CPU loads?,
Every request causes (depending on the route) an Api request or fetch operation from local JS files, and data nests from layout.server.js to page.svelte.
Actually, if the page is not cached, it takes like 1-2 seconds to load whole page (I think because of the images/gifs)
Maybe those requests triggers loads of resource fetching that loads my CPU and causes crashes.
But the thing that I can't get is NATRO says that isn't our problem, but my VPS becomes unreachable over SSH...

Every request causes (depending on the route) an Api request or fetch operation from local JS file  simply don't do that - design your architecture so that it is unnecessary

Thanks, I will handle that issue too. (If not a route it directly shows 404 page tho)
There are some people that faces the same issue: Their CPU peeks to 100% and becomes unreachable over SSH connection. I believe that there are problems with my PM2 setup or something, should I limit CPU usage of my PM2 instance?

Usually this is less of an issue on VPS that has multiple CPUs allocated. If you have only one CPU then it might become big issue. But you can limit CPU usage of a process nevertheless if it is a Linux server.

I have set my --max-memory-restart to 1300MB (I have 2GB ram on VPS), and it seems to be more stable, now.
Those spikes aren't happening for 2 days straight. But if it happens again, I will try to upgrade my VPS specs to like 2 core and 4GB one.
